# How to upload single php web page to cpanel

Tags: php, ftp, cpanel

I've been trying to upload a web page containing PHP to cPanel. Is it necessary for the file to have the extension .html when uploading to cPanel?

When I upload the PHP file as it is, the page doesn't open.

Any suggestions how to add a single PHP page to cPanel?

Comment: It is possible to upload a PHP file, as well as, any other file type. Can you share your code and the error you see?

Answer (score 0):

> you  can zip your file first

and you can upload it from upload menu 
then you extrac it hope it help

Comment: I followed your steps exactly but the page couldn't open imgur.com/Nt59ZDc @huntz rahmadi

Answer (score 0):

File Manager

public_html folder

Upload File

Select PHP file

Navigate to site.com/file.php

Comment: I followed your steps exactly but the page couldn't open
https://imgur.com/Nt59ZDc @Nerdi.org

Comment: Please post the contents of the PHP page you made. Then make a new php page with only: <?php phpInfo(); ?> And show me results please